# Access LAN via secondary/additional WAN

Tags: vpn, mobile-broadband

**Summary:**
I'd like to access LAN resources via (Open)VPN and an additional mobile broadband router (additional connection).

**Network properties:**
Asus RT-AC88U router with local IP 10.100.200.1 connected to a high speed network (and no option for port forwarding or VPN-passthrough) with private WAN IP 192.168.1.x and capability for dual WAN,
Asus 4G-AC53U mobile broadband router with dynamic public WAN IP. Router IP: 10.100.150.1

**Question:**
Is it possible to achieve that:

- all devices use the high speed network for "ordinary" traffic
- the mobile broadband connection is active (connected, not standby as hot standby implies no WAN IP being assigned) and can be used for OpenVPN-connections

**Additional info:**
I've tried:

- using the 4G-AC53U as "primary" router with the high speed network as
  primary WAN and the mobile as secondary and the RT-AC88U handling the LAN. However this results in DDNS not functioning.
- using the dual WAN functionality of the RT-AC88U (primary WAN = high speed, secondary WAN = 4G-AC53U) together with load balance in order to keep both WAN-connections active and direct traffic to the high speed port. Unfortunatly this resulted in either the LAN-resources not being accessible via VPN or LAN resources using the mobile broadband of the 4G-AC53U instead of the high speed LAN.

​
**Challenges:**

- Main challenge: high-speed primary WAN cannot be configured for VPN
- RT-AC88U dual WAN configuration: the secondary WAN is standby only, unless "Load balance" is activated (which - among others - implies that AiProtection cannot be used)
- in a RT-AC88U dual WAN configuration with the 4G-AC53U supplying the secondary WAN, I can establish a VPN-connection with the mobile broadband router, but neither with the RT-AC88U VPN nor with RT-AC88U-LAN

**Any ideas (other than Teamviewer) in order to get things sorted?**

Comment: `10.100.150.1` is *also* a private IP address. Your wireless broadband ISP most likely uses Carrier-grade NAT.

Comment: Sorry for the disambiguity. 10.100.150.1 is the LAN IP. The router is assigned a public IP address (when connected).

Comment: This is hard. Start off by getting dd-wrt on the router. You will then need to set up policy based routing.

Comment: @davidgo: Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping to be able to use the standard firmware.

Comment: Hm I see. Well either way my recommendation is to create an outgoing tunnel to a VPS or whatever. You wouldn’t require a secondary connection for that.